# vba macro for Array string

Tags: vba

```
Sub arraystring()
    Dim strname() As String, count As Integer
    Dim element As Variant
    count = 0
    strname = ("sathesh")
    For Each element In strname
    count = count + 1
    Next
    MsgBox "The total Count is" & count
End Sub
```

can some one help me out on the above code.I need to get the count of the string which is assigned in the array string.

Comment: You assigned a string "sathesh" to strname, but strname is declared as array of string.  This should be corrected at first.  You never be able to get count of string until you assign strings into strname.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `Len("string")`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to declare the string array with unknown dimensions, perhaps you should abandon the string array (and subsequent ReDim commands) in favor of a variant array.

`Sub arraystring()
    Dim strname As Variant, count As Long
    strname = Array("sathesh", "hsehtas")
    count = UBound(strname) + 1 'a variant array is zero based
    MsgBox "The total Count is " & count
End Sub`

The variant array is zero based so you need to add 1 to the upper boundary (i.e. count).